# RSpec starts_with matcher variant using regular expressions

Tags: ruby, regex, rspec, matcher

Is there a variant of the RSpec `start_with` matcher that will use regular expression matching instead of equality when examining arrays of strings?  (I don't mind writing my own; but I don't want to re-invent the wheel.)

Specifically, I want to have a spec that looks like this:

```
it 'begins with the standard header' do
  output = method_under_test
  # output is an array of Strings
  expect(output).to start_with([/foo/, /bar/])
end
```

This spec should pass if `output[0]` matches `/foo/` and `output[1]` matches `/bar/`.

Assuming I do need to write my own matcher, is there a way to "overload" `start_with`, or do I need to choose a different name?

Comment: You probably need to write your own matcher with a different name.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the solution is to use a combination of composing matchers and aliases:

```
it 'begins with the standard header' do
  output = method_under_test
  # output is an array of Strings
  expect(output).to start_with(
                a_string_matching(/foo/),
                a_string_matching(/bar/)
             )
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-10/docs/built-in-matchers/match-matcher

You can pass any valid regex
expect(output).to match(/foo/)

Comment: Nice.  Is this a newer feature, or did I just drop the ball back in 2016?

Comment: Depends what version of gem you were using it at that point. But seems like this has been around since https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-3/docs/built-in-matchers/match-matcher

I chiefly added a solution in case anyone else ran into this.