# Composing matchers in Rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

Rspec supports composing matchers. The list of composing matchers it provides is this:

```
all(matcher)
include(matcher, matcher)
start_with(matcher)
end_with(matcher)
contain_exactly(matcher, matcher, matcher)
match(matcher)
change {}.from(matcher).to(matcher)
change {}.by(matcher)
```

The all composing matcher is intuitive. You can pass matchers to the composing matcher and the passed matchers must return true for the expectation to be true:

```
expect(@items).to all(be_visible & be_in_stock)
```

But I am not certain about the start_with and end_with composing matcher. Look at this example:

```
fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry']
expect(fruits).to start_with( start_with('a') )
```

What are the outer and inner start_with doing in this example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, you are testing that the first element of `fruits` starts with the character `a`. So the outer `starts_with` targets the first element of array and the inner `starts_with` targets the beginning of the first element.

Your example passes, but for instance this fails:

```
fruits = ['banana', 'apple', 'cherry']
expect(fruits).to start_with( start_with('a') )
```

There are several examples in the [rspec-expectations tests](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/848fcb426cca1977b75909d0cb8a10f03a104b36/spec/rspec/matchers/built_in/start_and_end_with_spec.rb) of arrays where you want to test that the first element(s) start or end with a given value or string. For example:

```
expect([1.01, "food", 3]).to start_with(a_value_within(0.2).of(1), a_string_matching(/foo/))

expect([3, "food", 1.1]).to end_with(a_value_within(0.2).of(1))
```

Also related: [RSpec starts_with matcher variant using regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39254886/rspec-starts-with-matcher-variant-using-regular-expressions)

Comment: So the outer starts_with targets the first element of array, and the inner starts_with targets the first character of the first element.

Comment: exactly! I'll add that to the answer too.